# How to reduce margin when viewed on a tablet in portrait mode?

Tags: html, css

There is a huge margin/gap at the top when my site is viewed in portrait mode on a tablet. How can I reduce this?

Page is http://druvocals.com/Stack/home.html

[image]

Comment: Due to `.pos-vertical-center` rule, which positions with `top:50%` and applies transformation `translateY(-50%)`, which is basically a vertical centering technique.

Comment: Look into using css media queries

Answer (score 0):

You just can use position.`position: absolute` and `top:0` or whatever position you want.You just can use positioning task to set up it into your desired position.